# Skip the first characters form explode

Tags: php

i want to explode some file name like below but don't want to explode the first "iw5_m4a1_mp"
i need to skip the "iw5_m4a1_mp" so how i can do that?!
and also i have a problem in return array, its just returns first data?.

```
$weapon = iw5_m4a1_mp_eotech_silencer_texture;

function getWeaponThu($weapon = null) {

    $ThuName = $weapon;

    $spiltthum = explode('_', $ThuName);

    foreach($spiltthum as &$t){

    $ThuPath = "/img/";
    $ThuImg = $ThuPath . $t . ' .jpg ';

    return $ThuImg;

    }
}
```

**From comments:**

> there are always three values at the start of the file name but not always iw5_m4a1_mp the middle part is different like this iw5_pp90_mp i just want to skip three values at the start

Comment: Can you give us a complete filename example?

Comment: If the prefix you want to skip is fixed then use `substr` to take a substring that does not include it. Otherwise it's not clear how the question can be answered correctly.

Comment: iw5_m4a1_mp_eotech_silencer_texture this is complete file name

Comment: use `array_slice` after `explode`

Comment: @Jon after explode how to rerun values in array its just return first data

Comment: But do all your `$weapon` values consistently have that same prefix?

Comment: @taken: I understand the question, but you need to clarify.

Comment: Are there always three values at the start of the filename?  In this case you want to cut off `iw5_m4a1_mp`, are there always 3 parts like this that need cut?

Comment: `getWeaponThu($weapon = null, $prefix = "iw5_m4a1_mp")` then string replace... maybe

Comment: @Michael Berkowski yes

Comment: @Michael sorry i must say there are always three values at the start of the file name but not always iw5_m4a1_mp the middle part is different like this iw5_pp90_mp i just want to skip three values at the start

Comment: preg_replace then ;p effforrrrt

Comment: can someone make me clear by an example or with my code ?!

Comment: Guys pleas :( someone make an example

Comment: Hold on please - it's on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$weapon = 'iw5_m4a1_mp_eotech_silencer_texture';
function getWeaponThu($weapon = null) {
    if (!$weapon)
        return;
    $spiltthum = explode('_', $weapon);
    $ThuImg = [];
    for ($i = 3; $i < count($spiltthum); $i++)
        array_push($ThuImg,'/img/' . $spiltthum[$i] . '.jpg');
    return $ThuImg;
}
print_r(getWeaponThu($weapon));
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /img/eotech.jpg
    [1] => /img/silencer.jpg
    [2] => /img/texture.jpg
)
```

Comment: Thank you but as you see i want in  foreach($spiltthum as &$t){ i need to return in split such as eotech.jpg and silencer.jpg and texture.jpg not all in one

Comment: @taken that wasn't what you asked for originally. You would have to return an array of images. Is that what you need?

Comment: Edited reply to return the array.

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski i asked : and also i have a problem in return array, its just returns first data?.

Comment: If you're speaking of the code i wrote, you just need to ser a var like this  `$weapon_array = getWeaponThu($weapon);` and then use `$weapon_array[N]` where N is index number. For example `echo $weapon_array[0];` will print "/img/eotech.jpg", `echo $weapon_array[1];` will print "/img/silencer.jpg", and so on...